# Game Physics Approximation: Object interaction with water. How can I simulate buoyant force?

Tags: math, game-physics, game-development, godot, gdscript

I am making a physics-based game in Godot about kayaking down a river. I am using v3.1.1.stable.official and GDscript. Water is displayed with a shader and I can create a plane or massive cubic shape that represents the surface.

I want to make a system to apply a force on the kayak based on how submerged it is in the flat simplification of the water level. The kayak has no set in stone shape yet. I want to apply the correct magnitude and direction of force at the accurate point on the boat based on what part of it and how much is submerged in the water.

I know that the buoyant force is p(the water density) times g(gravitational constant, 9.81m/s^2) times V(the volume submerged)

```
F=p*g*V
```

and that I can apply it at any point I wish.

```
apply_impulse(Vector3(.1, 0, 0), Vector3.UP*F)
add_force(Vector3(.1, 0, 0), Vector3.UP*F)
```

I think that the point to apply the force would be the 3d centroid of the volume that is submerged and that it would be angled perpendicular, straight out of the "plane" of the water, however, I am only guessing, I could easily be wrong.

I don't mind approximations like simplifying the boat to a 3d ellipse. I have a good grasp of both physics up through kinematics and energy, and calculus up through derivatives. I could learn integrals or other calculus functions if those are useful, however, I'm hoping that there is some sort of built-in Godot function that can save me from 3d calculus and writing a complex 3d function for the hull of the kayak.

TLDR, I need a way to find:

1. the volume of a boat that is submerged at any orientation/position in an idealized flat body of water
2. the point on the boat at which the force should be applied
3. the direction the force should be in

Comment: Someone has created a [hydrodynamics module](https://gitlab.com/ringtechsolutions/godot-tools/hydro/hydro/-/wikis/home) for Godot. You might be able to save yourself a lot of work by using this, or at least learn something by reading the source.